# Generating a salt in PHP

Tags: php, random, cryptography, salt

What's the best way to generate a cryptographically secure 32 bytes salt in PHP, without depending on libraries seldom included in typical PHP installations?

After some googling I discovered that `mt_rand` is not considered secure enough, but I haven't found a suggestion for a replacement. One article suggested reading from `/dev/random` but not only this won't work on windows; it is also **very** slow.

I want a reasonable balance between security and speed (ie, it shouldn't take 20 seconds to generate 512 bytes, like `/dev/random` usually does)

Comment: `/dev/urandom` can be used for faster generation, but still won't work on Windows systems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Note**: `mcrypt` has been deprecated in PHP 7.1. [Skip to the up-to-date answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34173258/2373138).

You might want to take a look at the documentation (and comments) for [`mcrypt_create_iv()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php).

Comment: mcrypt is deprecated in PHP 7.1 . You shouldn't write code that is already deprecated. So if you read this in 2016, don't use this answer, prefer @Scott Arciszewski 's one.

Comment: mcrypt_create_iv() will be deprecated so better to use random_bytes() as suggested here - http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php

Answer (score 25):

This is easier in PHP 7:
 Just use [`$salt = random_bytes($numberOfDesiredBytes);`](https://secure.php.net/random_bytes) to generate a salt.

What do you need a salt for, anyway? If it's for passwords, just use [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify).

Comment: Thanks for the note about `password_hash`. Turn out it works better for me than the original solution.

Answer (score 9):

> **Note**: `mcrypt` has been deprecated in PHP 7.1. [Skip to the up-to-date answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34173258/2373138).

You can use the function `mycrypt_create_iv()`, since PHP Version 5.3 it also uses the random source on a Windows server (not only on Unix). Before using it, you should check if the constant `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` is defined.

```
mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
```

Unlike random, urandom does not block the server, if there is not enough entropy available. Since the password salt should be unique (not necessarily random), urandom seems to be a good choice to me.

Comment: Please note that the second argument is optional and the value `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` is the default - so if you don't want to change it, you can just as well do `mcrypt_create_iv($length)`. More over, this feature is implemented in the `mcrypt` extension which may or may not be installed on your server. Lastly, the result of that function is a binary string which is often not what you need, as you want to save the salt for referencing later. I usually `base64_encode` the result before using it as a salt.

Comment: @Guss - These are good points. Moreover one needs to check, in what form the salt is expected. BCrypt for example will not accept a binary salt, but a base64 encoded salt isn't valid neither. For password hashing it is best to use the built in function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which generates a safe salt on its own.

Comment: One reason not to use `password_hash()` is that I'm not implementing a password. I need a salt to implement a stateless "api key" style authorization protocol.

Comment: In addition, password_hash() is not available on all servers.  My server, for example, is stuck on php 5.3.  password_hash() is not available until 5.5.

Comment: @RoboticRenaissance - This should not be a problem, there is a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for 5.3.7 and later. With a minor tweak it can be used even with 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

**`uniqueid`** is not well suited for generating a random string as it too is `microtime` based.
A CPU Cycle is generally much shorter than a microtime-tick, which may lead to possible constancy for a given variable within loops.
Setting the second parameter "entropy" to true,

```
 uniqid('', true)
```

will provide increased randomness.

To get a random string that is well compatible with most character-sets,one may apply base64 encoding to the *mcrypt* initilization vector function `mcrypt_create_iv`:

```
$length = 16;
base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(ceil(0.75*$length), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))
//> hlZuRJypdHFQPtI2oSFrgA==
strlen(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(ceil(0.75*$length), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)))
//> 16
```

Reducing the character-alphabet to 2^6Bit increases the size, which is accounted for above.

Answer (score 1):

Read from `/dev/urandom`, or use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question has an accepted answer but I just want to additionally state after a bit of research and reading this thread that you might add some security if you don't put all your eggs in one basket.

I might suggest not relying solely on PHP to create your salts and hashing your passwords.  You can obfuscate your solution a little more if you let the database do part of the work.

Someone suggested just using password_hash() and password_verify(). While those are great methods, I strongly recommend sticking to the idea of incorporating a salt in addition to these.

To answer the question, a salt can be anything that is truly random and enforced as unique to the user.  You can technically generate it however you wish as long as you adhere to those 2 rules.

a couple of good resources:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right
https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/

Answer (score -2):

[uniqid()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) should be fine for this purpose.

Comment: I use uniqid() with some fast computable seed value (like the suggested microtime), too. Haven't done a cryptographic analysis, but seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score -7):

I think `microtime()` is enough.

Strangely, but I am still getting downvotes for this answer.

Though the only explanation I get is that microtime is predictable.
It sounds strange to me as salt always assumed as *openly known* - so, there is no use for prediction at all.

Comment: Not really. Not only it's very very easy to predict (it's the current time), I also can't get 32 bytes out of it.

Comment: @qster you can use it as random number generator. And get any number of bytes you want. And it is not the current time, you messed it up with time(). Microseconds do change pretty fast.
And it's only salt, you don't need too much security on salt.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Run `echo microtime()` through a for loop (10 loops is fine) and see how wrong you are...

Comment: Strangely, but some comments may contain a contradiction even in a single line:  "it's current time[stamp] but I can't get 32 bytes out of it". I've always thought that unix timestamp is a 32-bit number exactly.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: bits are not bytes.