# Difficulty in understanding how Salt works

Tags: php, password-encryption

So I am learning about encryption and I see there are several ways of doing it in PHP.
From what I have read, Salts can be random or not.

My question is, when the salt is randomly generated, how can you check for it when the user logs in?

And what would be the best way of creating salts apart from password_hash()(Since my php is 5.4.x)?

Thanks

Comment: Your second question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513734/generating-a-salt-in-php). Try not to put multiple questions in on Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to create salts yourself unless you know what you are doing. There is a good library here https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat that brings support for `password_hash()` for earlier versions of PHP. There is no reason not to use this.

Regarding the salt, it is stored alongside the password.

Answer (score 1):

> when the salt is randomly generated, how can you check for it when the user logs in?

You store the salt with the password hash.

Comment: -Quentin, would you mind making an example for me? I need a very clear example on how to make it. I have spent hours searching but it gets way too murky. Thanks

Comment: *Along with the password* would be more accurate. *With the password* sounds confusing.

Comment: `UPDATE users SET password=?, salt=? WHERE username=?`